# Turn on/off sorting arrows manually in Ag-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, classname, ag-grid-react

I use ag-grid grid and there i want to add custom behavior for ["asc/desc" arrows](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/) in columns header.

[image]

How can I turn on/off sorting arrows?

Comment: You should have a state providing these differents line no ? If yes, just remove the line you want from the state ?

Comment: Now I work with grid sorting, i want to manipulate with arrows that appear when i use asc/desc sorting

Comment: It's not recommended to manipulate classes directly with DOM in React. May I know what custom behavior do you want?

Comment: @Mobeen, I know, but I don't see another solution

Comment: @Mobeen, I want to turn on/off sorting arrows manually

Comment: Is hiding them with CSS an option?

Then you can assign class to any of the parent div/component ?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321894/how-to-hide-sort-order-indicator-in-ag-grid

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS thanks, here i found how can i remove arrow numbers

Comment: Sure I will update the answer with required info

Answer (score 0):

For me solution is [Sorting API](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/#sorting-api) (getSortModel, setSortModel)