# How to hide sort order indicator and show our own indicator icon for ascending and desending sort order in Ag-Grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321894/how-to-hide-sort-order-indicator-in-ag-grid)

I have same kind of colDef definition, and I am using angular 12 and ag-grid version 25.3.0.

Answer (score -1):

I get a way to add my icon.

```
 this.columnDefs = [
 {
   field: 'test',
  width: 150,
  icons: {
    sortAscending: '<i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-up"/>',
     sortDescending: '<i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-down"/>',
   },
 }];
```

I prefered this
[enter link description here](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/custom-icons/)